# How to automatically add default reviewers in gerrit when change owner adds +1?

Tags: git, gerrit

How to add reviewers to a Gerrit changeset when commit author/change owner reviews his own change by adding +1 to either 'code review' or 'verified' section? This is common practice that change owner makes multiple patchsets and when it is ready he marks +1 and adds other reviewers manually so that they can start reviewig. How can gerrit be configured to add reviewers automatically since we have the same set of reviewers for all patches?

Comment: Is this really *common* practice (i.e. not only for your project)? To me, the draft functionality of Gerrit sounds a lot more useful for this. And having a `+1` by the author is somewhat counter-intuitive since the patch will then appear as “reviewed” in all lists.

Comment: As poke said, use drafts for not-ready-for-review changes. It's the *common* workflow.

Comment: thanks, I did not know there was a draft functionality available in Gerrit and should review it. But just to answer this question for small teams working with closed source not having any external contributions or generation of lists, would simply a gerrit comment-added hook work? The commend-added hook script will simply check if comment author is same as change owner and if +1 was added as this is shown in comment field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functionality you ask is not present in Gerrit by default. However, for adding default reviewers for a project, there is [a plugin for it](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/reviewers/). That adds reviewers who would be always there for a given repository.

Other alternatives, as highlighted in [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/tlY3JS_C02g), is to ask the reviewers add the project as a watched project or write a hook for it. However I'd use the plugin.

The binary for the plugin is downloadable from jenkins ([2.12](https://gerrit-ci.gerritforge.com/view/Plugins-stable-2.12/job/plugin-reviewers-stable-2.12/), [2.11](https://gerrit-ci.gerritforge.com/view/Plugins-stable-2.11/job/plugin-reviewers-stable-2.11/), [master](https://gerrit-ci.gerritforge.com/view/Plugins-master/job/plugin-reviewers-master/)).

Comment: How to use the [plugin](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/reviewers/)